# Writing data back to dataframe after parallel computing in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, analytics, doparallel

I am new to Parallel computing in R.
I have gone through various links on StackOverFlow for the topic and wrote an initial code

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

detectCores()
## [1] 4
# Create cluster with desired number of cores
cl <- makeCluster(3)
# Register cluster
registerDoParallel(cl)
# Find out how many cores are being used
getDoParWorkers()
```

My objective is to do a repetitive calculation on each row, my function looks something like

```
func2<-function(i)
{
  msgbody<-tolower(as.character(purchase$msg_body[i]))
  purchase$category[i]<-category_fun(i,msgbody)  
}
```

For this purpose I have written a foreach loop

```
foreach(i = 1:nrow(purchase)) %dopar% func2(i)
```

But, the issue is that "func2" is supposed to write back to dataframe but it is not writing anything back, all the entries are same as old

Appreciate you help.

Comment: Are you saving the `foreach` result to anything? Also, you will probably need to export some variables to all the workers. Try running your code in a small dummy dataset first.

Comment: Your function is missing a proper return value. Especially with parallel processing it is very important that you do proper functional programming. Pass every object that is needed inside the function as a function argument and return every object you need outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work better in the scenario you're indicating. You can write a function that works on each msg_body string:

```
    func2 <- function(msg_body)
    {
      return(category_fun(i,tolower(as.character(purchase$msg_body[i])))  
    }

    result <- foreach(i=1:nrow(purchase),.combine=c) %dopar% {func2(purchase$msg_body[i]}

   purchase$category <- result
```

I do think you'll be better off using `apply()` to solve this though.